# Is there a way to make zsh run a command after REPORTTIME?

Tags: zsh

If a process takes greater than REPORTTIME, zsh prints the time when it finishes. Is there a way to make it run a custom command in addition to this?(I would like to use notify send to let me know the process finished executing)

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same thought. Did a quick google and found [this](http://contrapunctus.net/blog/2009/growl-upon-completion); I've adapted it a bit. Shove this into your zshrc:

```
if [[ -x `which notify-send` ]]; then
    notify-preexec-hook() {
        zsh_notifier_cmd="$1"
        zsh_notifier_time="`date +%s`"
    }

    notify-precmd-hook() {
        local time_taken

        if [[ "${zsh_notifier_cmd}" != "" ]]; then
            time_taken=$(( `date +%s` - ${zsh_notifier_time} ))
            if (( $time_taken > $REPORTTIME )); then
                notify-send "task finished" \
                    "'$zsh_notifier_cmd' exited after $time_taken seconds"
            fi
        fi
        zsh_notifier_cmd=
    }
fi

[[ -z $preexec_functions ]] && preexec_functions=()
preexec_functions=($preexec_functions notify-preexec-hook)

[[ -z $precmd_functions ]] && precmd_functions=()
precmd_functions=($precmd_functions notify-precmd-hook)
```

I'm rather happy with it! :)

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: @slm -- that makes a lot of sense. edited

Comment: FYI it's simpler to add a function hook via `add-zsh-hook` as described here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Manipulating-Hook-Functions